# plantuml mi diagrama enorme se ve cortado

Tags: plantuml

Hice un diargama enorme en plantuml para representar un path de carrera, pero le puse tantos elementos que ya no se muestra completo.

¿Hay alguna forma de que se muestre la parte que falta o que me lo parta en dos diagramas cuando alcance la altura máxima?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede cambiar le tamaño máximo como lo indica [en su documentación](https://plantuml.com/faq), se procede a agregar una variable de sistema con el valor que queramos, por defecto el máximo es 4096.

La Variable de sistema se debe de llamar `PLANTUML_LIMIT_SIZE`.

[image: estableciendo variable de sistema]